# Codeigniter Pagination not working correctly with db query

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, pagination, codeigniter-2

I'm not getting success in integrating paging with the result of my select with codeigniter.

I'm starting to work with codeigniter and I am unable to make a pagination correctly. The links are created correctly, they put no limits, and the links do not go anywhere. below are all the codes

Model

```
public function listProvas($i = 0, $nRows = 0){
    //return $data['provas'] = $this->db->get('provas')->result_array();
    return $this->db->query('SELECT `idProva` , `provas`.`titulo` AS `nome_prova` , `provas`.`ativo` , `atividades`.`idAtividade` , `modulos_x_tarefas`.`fkModulo` , `modulos`.`titulo` AS `modulo` , `disciplinas`.`disciplina`
                             FROM `provas` , `atividades` , `modulos_x_tarefas` , `modulos` , `disciplinas`
                             WHERE `provas`.`fkAtividade` = `atividades`.`idAtividade`
                             AND `atividades`.`idAtividade` = `modulos_x_tarefas`.`fkTarefa`
    ')->result_array();
}
```

controller

```
public function index($i = 0){
    $this->load->model('provasmodel');

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

    $nRows = 50;
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://URL/painel/listaprovas/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('provas')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = $nRows;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';


    $dados['provas'] = $this->provasmodel->listProvas($i, $nRows);
    $dados['total'] = count($this->provasmodel->listProvas($i, $nRows));
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $datapag['records'] = $this->db->get('provas', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['provas'] = $this->provasmodel->listProvas();
    $this->template->load('templates/template_painel', 'painel/lista_provas', $data, $datapag);
}
```

view

```
<?php foreach ($provas as $data): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $data['idProva']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['nome_prova']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['modulo']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['disciplina']; ?></td>
          <td>numero</td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Comment: can you add the links you are getting?

Comment: of corse, @kumar_v ...  "http://url/painel/listaprovas/50", "http://url/painel/listaprovas/100" .... "http://url/painel/listaprovas/200"

Comment: here 50 , 100, 200 is page number or per page count?

Comment: @kumar_v is the number that I set to the number of results per page, "$nRows = 50;"

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: yes @kumar_v, I'm checking other ways, will post results soon

Answer (score 0):

You are missing uri_segement option in pagination config.

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Change the number as per your project url.

uri_segment is for `page number` not `per page count`.

The pagination function automatically determines which segment of your URI contains the page number. If you need something different you can specify it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors in the code, one was not setting a limit on my SQL call.
Two, the base url was not calling the index method.

Thanks for the tips.

Model

```
 public function listProvas($i = 0, $nRows = 0){
//return $data['provas'] = $this->db->get('provas')->result_array();
return $this->db->query('SELECT `idProva` , `provas`.`titulo` AS `nome_prova` , `provas`.`ativo` , `disciplinas`.`disciplina`
                         FROM `provas` , `atividades` , `modulos_x_tarefas` , `modulos` , `disciplinas`
                         WHERE `provas`.`fkAtividade` = `atividades`.`idAtividade`
                         AND `atividades`.`idAtividade` = `modulos_x_tarefas`.`fkTarefa´ LIMIT '.$i.','.$nRows.'

')->result_array();
```

controller

```
public function index($i = 0, $nRows = 100){
    $this->load->model('provasmodel');
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http:/url/painel/listaprovas/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('provas')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = $nRows;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $data['provas'] = $this->provasmodel->listProvas($i, $nRows);
    $data['total'] = count($this->provasmodel->listProvas($i, $nRows));
    $datapag['records'] = $this->db->get('provas', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['provas'] = $this->provasmodel->listProvas($i, $nRows);
    $this->template->load('templates/template_painel', 'painel/lista_provas', $data);
}
```

}

view

```
<?php foreach ($provas as $data): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $data['idProva']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['nome_prova']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['modulo']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['disciplina']; ?></td>
          <td>numero</td>
          <?php
            if ($data['ativo'] == '1') {
              echo '<td class="ativo">Ativo</td>';
            }else{
              echo '<td class="inativo">Inativo</td>';
            }
          ?>
          <td><a href="/painel/prova/<?php echo $data['idProva']; ?>" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

      </tbody>
    </table>


        </div><!--table-responsive--
  <?php echo $pagination; ?>
```